# Sort an array of objects according to rank of different object

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Objects as below.

```
var options = [
  {value: 'b', label: "test1"},
  {value: 'a', label: "test12"},
  {value: 'c', label: "test123"}
]
```

and an array of ranks as below.

```
var ranks = [
  {rank: 1, value: "a"},
  {rank: 2, value: "b"},
  {rank: 3, value: "c"}
]
```

Now I need to sort the `options` array according to the `rank` property in `ranks` array

Comment: What have you tried, what has your own prior research led you to?

Comment: can you explain more detailed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bring down the complexity and improve performance, you can first create a `temp` **object/map** with `key` as `obj.value` and `rank` as `value`. Then simply use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort on the basis of rank stored in the temp object.

```js
let options = [{value: 'b', label: "test1"},{value: 'a', label: "test12"},{value: 'c', label: "test123"}];
let ranks = [{rank: 1, value: "a"},{rank: 2, value: "b"},{rank: 3, value: "c"}]; 

let temp = ranks.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a,{[c.value]:c.rank}), {});
options.sort((a,b) => temp[a.value] - temp[b.value]);
console.log(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var options = [
  {value: 'b', label: "test1"},
  {value: 'a', label: "test12"},
  {value: 'c', label: "test123"}
]


var ranks = [
  {rank: 1, value: "a"},
  {rank: 2, value: "b"},
  {rank: 3, value: "c"}
]

             
options.sort((a, b) => {
  return ranks.find(_ => _.value === a.value).rank - ranks.find(_ => _.value === b.value).rank
})

console.log (options)
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and take this as closure for sorting.

```js
var options = [{ value: 'b', label: "test1" }, { value: 'a', label: "test12" }, { value: 'c', label: "test123" }],
    ranks = [{ rank: 1, value: "a" }, { rank: 2, value: "b" }, { rank: 3, value: "c" }];
    
options.sort(
    (m => ({ value: a }, { value: b }) => m.get(a) - m.get(b))
    (ranks.reduce((m, { rank, value }) => m.set(value, rank), new Map))
);

console.log(options);
```